# The definition of While loop

Tags: autoit

I just started studying Autoit and I am having trouble in understanding while loop statement.

I'm trying to make a script that is intended to go to another site when Image 'a.bmp' is exposed. The image 'a.bmp' will be a favicon of a certain site.

So the script below is made to perceive favicon 'a.bmp'

**$search = _ImageSearch('a.bmp',0,0,0,0)
   While $search = _ImageSearch('a.bmp',0,0,0,0)
      Sleep(10)
   WEnd**

This script actually works fine. It exits the loop and do the next action when 'a.bmp' appears. But the problem is that I've realized later on that the while loop is executed when the expression ( $search = _ImageSearch('a.bmp',0,0,0,0) is 'true'.

if the definition of while loop I've mentioned is correct, isn't the loop above should go through an infinite loop when the 'a.bmp' appears?

I'm so confused. I'd appreciate it if anyone answers..

Answer (score 2):

You cant assign a value where expression is expected!

```
While $search = _ImageSearch
```

This doesnt assign a value to $search, but just checks if the $search is equal to _ImageSearch.

From the help file:

Loop based on an expression.

```
While <expression>
    statements
    ...
WEnd
```

If the expression is true the following statements up to the WEnd statement are executed. This loop continues until the expression is false.

So, what happens in your example?

```
$search = _ImageSearch('a.bmp',0,0,0,0)
While $search = _ImageSearch('a.bmp',0,0,0,0)
Sleep(10)
WEnd
```

First ImageSearch fails and sets $search to 0.
Under While loop you have an expression $search = _ImageSearch, which will be true if _ImageSearch fails again.

Basicaly you got **While 0=0 Wend** and as soon as the image appeared, the loop ended.

The correct code would be

```
While Not _ImageSearch('a.bmp',0,0,0,0)
Sleep(10)
WEnd
```

To further improve your code I would use only one line of code.

```
_WaitForImageSearch('a.bmp',0,0,0,0, 30); Will wait max 30 seconds for a.bmp to appear
```